# How can I split a DataFrame into multiple DataFrames of fewer rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

If I have a `DataFrame` that is composed of 100 rows w/ 4 columns for sake of example, how can I create 5 new `DataFrames` that are each composed of 20 rows w/ 4 columns?

That is, if an arbitrary column of the original `DataFrame` holds the list `[0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 98, 99]`, how would I create 5 new `DataFrames` such that the first `DataFrame`'s arbitrary column holds the list `[0, 1, 2, ..., 9]`, the second `DataFrame`'s arbitrary column holds the list `[10, 11, 12, ..., 19]`, etc. etc.?

I tried the following to a `DataFrame` consisting of a single column `A` that holds the list `[0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 98, 99]`, but it gave me 100 `CSV` files each w/ a single row rather than the desired 5 CS`enter code here`V files each w/ 20 rows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
list = []
for i in range (0, 100):
    list.append(i)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=list, columns=['A'])
groups = df['A'].groupby(np.arange(len(df['A']/10)))
for (frameno, frame) in groups:
    frame.to_csv("/Users/ephemeralhappiness/Desktop/Cycle Test/" + "%s.csv" % frameno)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your groupby to:

```
# to get 5 groups
nrows = 20
groups = df.groupby(df.index // nrows)

print(groups.ngroups)
5
```

Comment: Would you consider `desired = 5 ; groups = df.groupby( df.index // ( len(df) / desired ) )` a reasonable generalization?

Comment: @Mark that should generate the same number of groups